# Matrimony website in Joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

we have got a new project related to Matrimony and our management wants to use Joomla for this. I suggested that it can be done well in core php or any framework, but my boss asks why cant we do it in Joomla.

But i oppose it to the point that Joomla is not suited for a site like matrimony.
I think it would be very complex for developing the design and functionality in Joomla, than with a normal php site.

I doubt whether it would be fair to go ahead with Joomla for this purpose.
Can anyone tell me what i needed to do this in Joomla, if it is a feasible solution.
I especially want to know how to do the design of inner pages with joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla in its core has good template and CMS functionality. If your site is all about publishing content and requires good template then you can chose joomla as your choice. Learning i guess would not be tough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would consider Joomla for this project, though i would still prefer core php as the better choice in this case. Anyway, now i want to learn how can i code my own functionality in Joomla.